# React/Next js, set active class on a button based on index

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-table

Im working on creating a dashboard/table and Im stuck on styling the pagination portion, setting an active class on click. Im using react-tables and react-tables build in pagination. By default, react tables doesn’t have the pagination look Im trying to get so I used map to go through all the buttons and display them accordingly. Now, Ive tried using useState and changing it on click, but when I click on a button all of them get the active class not just the selected one. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

const toggleIsActive = () => {
    setIsActive(!isActive);
};
  
<div className={styles.pagination}>
    {pageOptions.map((option, i) => (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
              gotoPage(i);
              toggleIsActive(), i
          }}
          key={i}
          className={isActive ? styles.active : ""}
        >
            {option + 1}
        </button>
    ))}{" "}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `isActive` to save the index of active

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(null);
const toggleIsActive = (i) => {
  setIsActive(i);
};

onClick={() => {
  gotoPage(i);
  toggleIsActive(i);
}}
className={isActive === i ? styles.active : ""}
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! Im new to coding and still learning. I really appreciate it!

Comment: You can vote me this is the correct answer

Comment: I tried but I dont have enough rep to do it :( Its my very first post

Comment: It has a icon check to accept this anwser